# Underline two cells with a continuous line in table

Tags: tables, columns, underline, nicematrix

My code is like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{A} \\
    \hline 
    AID & A1 \\
    \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Which compile as:

[image]

How can I underline AID and A1 with a same line? Like this:

[image]

I expected replacing `\underline{AID & A1}` on the line 5 do the trick, but it seems I was wrong.

Comment: Use of `tikzmark` package may be a one way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the underline will not cross the border of cells, a pseudo underline must be drawn manually.

The `nicematrix` package allows you to use `tikz` commands using as a reference the nodes it creates in the cells.

The parameters of the line depend on the content of the cells, so in this solution it may be necessary to slightly adjust the length of the line or the vertical offset manually.

As a bonus, when using the `hvlines` option, the package will draw all vertical and horizontal lines (second table, *using the same parameters for the line*). `\Block` makes a multicolum cell.

Due to the use of tikz nodes, it will be necessary to compile it twice the first time.

To make the line extend to the right and left, use

`\tikz \draw [shorten < =  0.7\tabcolsep, shorten > = 0.7\tabcolsep] ...`

[image: f]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \Block{1-2}{A} &\\
    \hline 
    AID & A1 \\
    \hline 
    \CodeAfter
    \tikz \draw [shorten < =  \tabcolsep, shorten > = \tabcolsep]  ([yshift=0.7ex]3-|1) -- ([yshift=0.7ex]3-|3); 
\end{NiceTabular}
\bigskip    

\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}[hvlines] %<<< draw all the table lines
    \Block{1-2}{nicematrix} & \\
    AID4u & SWYP \\
    \CodeAfter
    \tikz \draw [shorten < = \tabcolsep, shorten > =  \tabcolsep]  ([yshift=0.7ex]3-|1) -- ([yshift=0.7ex]3-|3); 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```